# Usercontrol, resize inside the grid

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a typical user control with some drawing on the canvas.I have plugged that user control in a grid with following code

```
 <Routine:FlashUserControl x:Name="FlashControl" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Grid.RowSpan="9" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />,
```

but the user control overflow above the grid region (as specified in the attached image) rather than fitting into the region (2 Coloumns x 9 rows)

Even Though VerticalAlignment, HorizontalAlignment, HorizontalContentAlignment and  VerticalContentAlignment defined as stretch in user control, why it is happening?

[image]

UPDATE:

If I summarize the issue, my drawing entities inside the usercontrol exceeds the canvas limits, I think I need to re-scale the drawings

Comment: What is that `Routine:FlashUserControl` control? It looks to me it encapsulates some native (GDI based) control. Note that WPF's rendering engine is independent of the traditional GDI, and any native (GDI) control hosted by WPF is laid over the WPF UI. I guess either Routine:FlashUserControl is limited and requires explicit width/height declarations, or it might have a bug (i.e. not resizing the native control properly according to WPF's layout procedure...)

Comment: @elgonzo , it is a wpf based user control. I can't specify the width and height of it. Because if I fixed those, it cannot be changed further

Comment: I doubt that the Routine:FlashUserControl is a true WPF control. The name indicates that it has something to do with Adobe Flash (which is an ActiveX control, and thus GDI/GDI+-based). If i would be wrong, how would you explain that the control seems to "leak" outside of the grid cell? (If the control were a WPF control and simply too large, the grid would adjust its size according to the control size, or?)

Comment: Anyway, the information given points towards a bug with the layout routine of that control, and you should inform its author about that issue.

Comment: @elgonzo, actually it is my wpfcontrol and I developed it. I kjust made the name as Routine, I changed the name to another one. It is same. I made it as a usercontrol because I want to plug it into mainform

Comment: Okay, so your FlashUserControl hosts an ActiveX (i.e. GDI-based) control, correct?

Comment: @elgonzo, it is pure wpf made out of canvas and canvas contains line arc and text. all wpf entities

Comment: Ah, okay, i see. The "Flash" part in the control's name got me lured on to a wrong path. Sorry about my obsession with Adobe Flash :) I guess the red area is actually an rectangle drawn onto the Canvas. If this is the case, the suggested approach is to fix the calculation of the coordinates of that rectangle. However, as a quick validation of my assumption regarding that rectangle, set `ClipToBounds="True"` on the canvas and check whether the red rectangle still leaks...

Comment: Another assumption is that the FlashUserControl is actually not a child of the Grid (check your XAML). If this assumption also is wrong, then please add the respective XAML portion(s) to your question, so one can see what you do there...

Comment: @elgonzo, actually my usercontrol entity size is bigger than the grid space I need to plug in the main form. So User control should be re-sized to fit the space. If I clip, then I will use the needed part in the usercontrol and It is a child of the grid. See, it is mentioned as  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56502/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-robin).

Answer (score 0):

There can only be two reasons why a UI element that has been set into a particular section of a `Grid` might exceed its bounds. The fist reason might be that as mentioned in the comments, the UI element has had its `Width` and/or `Height` property values explicitly set to values that are too big for its available area. The fix for this is obviously to *not* explicitly set these values.

The second reason might simply be that you `Grid` has not been declared correctly. Perhaps you have the wrong number of rows and/or columns? Again, the fix for this is simple. Please show your `Grid` so that we can verify this point.

Comment: @@Sheridan my child UI element values that are too big for its available area. How to control this? I haven't set Canvas width or Heigght, bt internally my canvas has some elements

Comment: If you're using a third party control that sets its size internally and won't let you change it, then there's nothing you can do, except perhaps to find or define a new control.